# How can I use Java 7 with browsers in OS X 10.8?

Tags: plugins, safari, osx-mountain-lion, java-applet, java

I've downloaded [Java 7 Update 9 from java.com](http://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp?locale=en). I've installed it. I can see the icon in my System Preferences.

[image]

So now I quit and reopen Safari v6.0.2 and try to use Java and I get a dialog asking my to install and older version of java.

[image]

So I think, ok... well let's try Chrome and I get some message saying Chrome is crappy.

[image]

So I look for 64-bit Chrome and google says FU, between 2009 and 2012 we don't want to do anything.

[image]

So I hate to, but I download Firefox. I get the same Java 6 dialog...

[image]

I need Java for my work's VPN. How do I get an updated, not full of bugs Java that's already installed as a plugin to work in a browser?

Comment: Well, have you tried installing the Java 6 runtime (the one that you're offered)?

Comment: There are a ton of known issues with java 6 - known malware, etc. its also supposed to be EOL soon. I would rather not deal with 6 and just get 7 working.

Comment: Thats crazy....Once you have Java installed, you should definitely keep it updated. You greatly increase the danger of something bad happening if you are running an out-of-date version of Java. It would be like buying a new car, and then ignoring the important safety recall. Apple should definitely provide an update for this !!

Answer (score 1):

These commands worked for me (from [How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 web plug-in and Web Start functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559)).

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled 
sudo mv /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled
sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/javaws /usr/bin/javaws
```

Even then, my Java site only ran on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. You have to trick OSX into thinking its Java 6 though. For whatever reason OSX 10.8 doesn't recognize Java 7.

```
sudo mkdir /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
```

Comment: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk` doesn't exist. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is empty.

Comment: I just have the JRE installed... I do not need a full development environment.